# Local start/debug Spring Boot Application from dependency and include SPI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have a large project that runs after deploying, but I do not know how to start it local (Eclipse, Intellij).
We have in our core project a start configuration with a main method and it is marked as @SpringBootApplication. The core project is a dependency of our email project and some other projects. Also we have a SPI that depends on target system.

I want to debug all 3 projects at once - core, email and the active SPI. I have two major problems:

1. How to start the spring application? The IDE can not find the main method from the dependency. It is not a web server but an application that uses spring annotations to start.
2. How to add the SPI project with source code, so I can debug it?

Also I have to mention that we use Gradle with single project builds. We will update to Java 17 and maybe it is easier to solve if we create a multiproject in Gradle? What should a build script for this use case look like?

Comment: The setup of your project is not clear. You have one Spring Boot application, right? What kind of applications are the other two - Email? SPI?

Comment: SPI is a simple Java Service Provider Interface. Email is a Java project with Core dependency. It includes Spring Configuration, but has no class to start. Does this make it a Spring Boot Application, too?

Comment: This is a badly formulated question that is basically asking us (people who have never seen your project) how to start it? Ask your teammates - how should we know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to debug multiple projects by using [Gradle Composite Builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html). Add the core project and the SPI project to the email project in settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'projEmail'

includeBuild '../projCore'
includeBuild '../projLinux'  //SPI
```

The SPI must be added as test dependency, too. Then it is possible to write a starter class in the test sources - similar to the one in the core project:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    LOG.info("Start email project with Spring Boot");
    
    //Call the class in core that starts spring (class with @SpringBootApplication)
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MainAppSpringConfiguration.class);
    app.run(args);
}
```

So there is nothing special to do. I had to stop searching for an answer at similar questions and follow the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/using.html#using.running-your-application.from-an-ide): "You can run a Spring Boot application from your IDE as a Java application.".